# Condition inside table

Tags: php, loops, foreach

How to make a condition inside table in php with foreach?

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $dtrpt)
        {
            $cRet .='
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="font-size:12px;">'.$dtrpt['tgl_bukti'].'</td>
                <td align="center" style="font-size:12px;">'.$dtrpt['no_kas'].'</td>
                <td align="center" style="font-size:12px;">'.$dtrpt['tipe'].'</td>
                <td align="center" style="font-size:12px;">'.number_format($dtrpt['nilai'], 2, ',', '.').'</td>
                <td align="center" style="font-size:12px;">'.number_format($dtrpt['nilai'], 2, ',', '.').'</td>
                <td align="center" style="font-size:12px;">'.number_format($dtrpt['nilai'], 2, ',', '.').'</td>
            </tr>

            ';
}
```

Comment: what condition? where? Have you tried something?

Comment: What condition? How have you tried to implement it?

Comment: im trying to get result from database and filter it with if condition, with if condition, i had tried with if but get null return

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
echo '<td>' . ($data['temperature'] < 5 ? 'Cold' : 'Warm') . '</td>';
```

The above uses the ternary operator as a contracted if/else within a table cell.

Comment: absolutely like this, thank you man :D